# Partial derivatives of the dependent variable.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I have a function of the form $$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{\exp((y-\mu)/\tau)+1 }$$ where $\mu,\tau,m$ are constants. Also $y^2=x^2+m^2$. How do I calculate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$. Can I just not substitute the value of y in the expression?

Comment: Are you sure that the question is complete? Since it seems that $f$ is a function of $y$ only and so we just have to replace $\partial$ by $\text{d}$.

Comment: I am sure that this is the question. btw, are you trying to tell me that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0$ for the given expression? Why cannot I substitute the expression of y(x) here?

Comment: I mean that the partial derivative is the same as the regular one. And yes, you can definitely substitute.

Answer (score 0):

If $\mu$, $\tau$,and $m$ are really constants, then $f$ is purely a function of $y$, i.e.

$$f(x,y)=f(y)=\frac{1}{\exp((y-\mu)/\tau)+1 }= \frac{1}{exp((\sqrt{x^2 + m^2} - \mu ) / \tau ) -1}$$

The partial derivatives are then just the regular derivatives, so you just differentiate as you would normally.